# Biased coin probability calculation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, bayesian

I have a biased coin with 2/3 chance of heads (and thus 1/3 chance of tails). Question is: **given** that there was at **least one head in 3 flips**, what is the probability that **there is only 1 head**?

How would I solve this?

Comment: Divide the probability of there being exactly 1head over the probability of there being at least 1head. Also, the probability of there being at least 1 head is 1- the probability of there being no heads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to set this up is that there might be $0,1,2$ or $3$ heads in the three flips, but we can discard the case of $TTT$ since that has no heads.

Then the a priori probabilities (ignoring the constraint that there was at least one head) are:

- $HHH: \left(\frac23\right)^3 \cdot \binom{3}{3} = \frac {8}{27}$
- $HHT, HTH, THH:  \left(\frac23\right)^2 \left(\frac13\right)^1 \cdot \binom{3}{2} = \frac {12}{27}$
- $HTT, THT, TTH: \left(\frac23\right)^1 \left(\frac13\right)^2 \cdot \binom{3}{1} = \frac {6}{27}$

The total is $\frac{26}{27}$ out of which only $\frac6{27}$ have exactly one head, so the answer is 
$$
\frac6{26}=\frac3{13}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{6}{26}$?

Comment: Im getting $$\frac{3}{13}$$ .. same as above answer.

Comment: Yes, as Mark himself said, the TTT should be discarded, so $\frac{6}{26} = \frac{3}{13}$.

Comment: Yes, you are right @paw88789.  I will make the change.